# How Spark and Executors behave in local-mode

Tags: apache-spark

There are several well-answered questions in StackOverflow about the local-mode of Spark, but I couldn't find the answer to my question, which is;

I know in local-mode spark creates one JVM for both driver and executor, so it means we have one executor with the number of cores (let's say 8) of our computer (if we run it with Local[*]), also as default Spark creates partitions with the same number of cores. (if we use sc.parallelize)

But in spark one RDD partition goes to one executor, if we have 8 partitions and one executor in local-mode, is it means we're doing operations on one partition at a time by using our 8 core, or somehow each core works on one partition?

Answer (score 2):

"But in spark one RDD partition goes to one executor"

This is wrong
In spark one partition DOES NOT go to one executor. One partition goes to one core.

this just completely answers your question. 8 different partitions are being processed by the 8 different cores in local mode.

If you are interested this could be a good read for you:

[https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/#:~:text=Every%20Spark%20executor%20in%20an,property%20in%20the%20spark%2Ddefaults](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/#:%7E:text=Every%20Spark%20executor%20in%20an,property%20in%20the%20spark%2Ddefaults).

Comment: You mean in cluster-mode, let's say standalone cluster, if I have 5 executors with each have 3 core, and 15 partitions, then will each partition go to one core, or will each partition go to one executor.
Another question arises, one executor can have multiple partitions?

Comment: the question is about local mode.